# Yocto - Bitbake RDEPENDS from External Shared library

Tags: shared-libraries, yocto, bitbake

I need to use an external Shared library (Built outside Yocto) in my application built with Yocto.

When I set

```
RDEPENDS_app = "${RECIPE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/libFile.so"
```

It fail with following error :

> NOTE: Runtime target '../tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/app/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libFile.so' is unbuildable, removing...
>   Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['./tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/app/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libFile.so']

How can I use a shared library that Yocto doesn't control in a recipe?

Thanks

Comment: you need to write a recipe that deploys that library, otherwise it cannot be a runtime dependency as it is not going to be part of the image.

Comment: I already create a recipe for it and in
do_install () { 
install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/git/libFile.so  ${D}/${libdir}
}
but no luck !

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved using :

1. Create a recipe and prepare the lib to be packaged.
2. Use the recipe name in the RDEPENDS

Comment: In fact, RDEPENDS is related to package name built from recipe, in your case, both recipe and package have the same name. DEPENDS on the other hand is related to recipe name.